# identify groups containing indicator

Tags: r, split, lapply

I would like to identify groups that contain an indicator.  In the example below I would like to identify `districts` that contain `county == 'other'`.  If any `county == 'other'` in a `district` then I would like an indicator variable to be `1`, else `0`, for each row in that district.  Below are several attempts at doing so with `split`, `lapply` and `any`, but none of them work.  Perhaps I could extract all rows for which `county == 'other'`, define an indicator as one for that subset, then merge that subset back with the original data set, but I keep thinking there must be an easier way.  Thank you for any advice.

```
df.1 <- read.table(text = '

    state    district    county    apples
       AA          EC        AB       100
       AA          EC        BC        10
       AA          EC        DC       150
       AA           C        FG       200
       AA           C     other        20
       AA           C        HC       250
       AA          WC        RT       300
       AA          WC        TT        30
       AA          WC     other       350

', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

desired.result <- read.table(text = '

    state    district    county    apples  indicator
       AA          EC        AB       100          0
       AA          EC        BC        10          0
       AA          EC        DC       150          0
       AA           C        FG       200          1
       AA           C     other        20          1
       AA           C        HC       250          1
       AA          WC        RT       300          1
       AA          WC        TT        30          1
       AA          WC     other       350          1

', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# various attempts that do not work

with(df.1, lapply(split(county, district), function(x) {any(x)=='county' <- 1} ))
with(df.1, lapply(split(county, district), function(x) {ifelse(any(x)=='other', 1, 0)} ))
with(df.1, lapply(split(county, district), function(x) {any(x)=='other'} ))
with(df.1, lapply(split(df.1  , district), function(x) {any(x$county)=='other'} ))
with(df.1, lapply(split(county, district), function(x) {x=='other'} ))
```

EDIT

Here is the subset / merge approach I mentioned above:

```
df.indicator <- df.1[df.1$county == 'other',]
df.indicator <- df.indicator[,1:2]
df.indicator$indicator = 1
merge(df.1, df.indicator, by=c('state', 'district'), all=TRUE)
```

I prefer using base R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(df.1)
dt[, indicator := 1*any(county == 'other'), by = district]

dt
#   state district county apples indicator
#1:    AA       EC     AB    100         0
#2:    AA       EC     BC     10         0
#3:    AA       EC     DC    150         0
#4:    AA        C     FG    200         1
#5:    AA        C  other     20         1
#6:    AA        C     HC    250         1
#7:    AA       WC     RT    300         1
#8:    AA       WC     TT     30         1
#9:    AA       WC  other    350         1
```

Here's a base solution - it's much slower and uglier, but if that's OP's thing, oh well :)

```
df.1$indicator = as.numeric(ave(df.1$county, df.1$district,
                                FUN = function(x) {1*any(x == "other")}))
```

Or

```
df.1$indicator <- with(df.1, ave(county=='other', district, FUN=max))
```

Or

```
df.1$indicator <- with(df.1, ave(county=='other', district, FUN=any)+0L)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I have been able to come up with so far using the apply family of functions:

```
df.1 <- read.table(text = '

    state    district    county    apples
       AA          EC        AB       100
       AA          EC        BC        10
       AA          EC        DC       150
       AA           C        FG       200
       AA           C     other        20
       AA           C        HC       250
       AA          WC        RT       300
       AA          WC        TT        30
       AA          WC     other       350

', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

z <- with(df.1, lapply(split( df.1, district), function(x) { merge(x, ifelse('other' %in% x$county, 1, 0), all=TRUE) } )) ; z
df.2 <- do.call(rbind, z)
rownames(df.2) = NULL
df.2
```

Giving:

```
  state district county apples y
1    AA        C     FG    200 1
2    AA        C  other     20 1
3    AA        C     HC    250 1
4    AA       EC     AB    100 0
5    AA       EC     BC     10 0
6    AA       EC     DC    150 0
7    AA       WC     RT    300 1
8    AA       WC     TT     30 1
9    AA       WC  other    350 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When attempting to implement the above two answers with my actual data I realized I had to account for a new variable `df.1$year` and I needed to meet more complex conditions before the indicator variable should be one: `df.1$county == 'other' & is.na(df.1$apples)` within `district` and `year`.  Below is a revised data set `df.1` and a revised `lapply` statement to implement these new conditions.  I have not gotten `ave` to work with these new conditions, but I did borrow some of eddi's code.

This revised scenario seemed too closely related to my original question to post a new question.

```
# identify district/year combinations containing >= 1 row in which county == 'other' & apples == NA

df.1 <- read.table(text = '

    state    district    county   year   apples
       AA          EC        A    1980     100
       AA          EC        B    1980      10
       AA          EC        C    1980     150
       AA           C        G    1980     200
       AA           C    other    1980      20
       AA           C        I    1980     250
       AA          WC        R    1980     300
       AA          WC        S    1980      NA
       AA          WC    other    1980     350
       AA          EC        A    1999    1100
       AA          EC        D    1999      NA
       AA          EC        E    1999    1150
       AA           C        H    1999    1200
       AA           C        I    1999     120
       AA           C        J    1999    1250
       AA          WC        R    1999    1300
       AA          WC    other    1999      NA
       AA          WC        T    1999    1350

', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df.1$my.grouping <- paste(df.1$district, df.1$year, sep = '')

z <- lapply(split( df.1, df.1$my.grouping), function(x) { merge(x, 1*any(x$county == "other" & is.na(x$apples)), all=TRUE)} )
df.2 <- do.call(rbind, z)
rownames(df.2) = NULL
df.2

   state district county year apples my.grouping y
1     AA        C      G 1980    200       C1980 0
2     AA        C  other 1980     20       C1980 0
3     AA        C      I 1980    250       C1980 0
4     AA        C      H 1999   1200       C1999 0
5     AA        C      I 1999    120       C1999 0
6     AA        C      J 1999   1250       C1999 0
7     AA       EC      A 1980    100      EC1980 0
8     AA       EC      B 1980     10      EC1980 0
9     AA       EC      C 1980    150      EC1980 0
10    AA       EC      A 1999   1100      EC1999 0
11    AA       EC      D 1999     NA      EC1999 0
12    AA       EC      E 1999   1150      EC1999 0
13    AA       WC      R 1980    300      WC1980 0
14    AA       WC      S 1980     NA      WC1980 0
15    AA       WC  other 1980    350      WC1980 0
16    AA       WC      R 1999   1300      WC1999 1
17    AA       WC  other 1999     NA      WC1999 1
18    AA       WC      T 1999   1350      WC1999 1
```